# Rocksdb: Assertion `last_ref' failed when closing DB while using unique pointers

Tags: rocksdb

I keep getting `` rocksdb_column_family_error_test: /rocksdb/db/column_family.cc:1236: rocksdb::ColumnFamilySet::~ColumnFamilySet(): Assertion `last_ref' failed. `` when I try to close/delete or go out of scope with rocksdb. It throws SIGABRT. That is, when I use std::unique_pointers for the database and column family handlers. I have attached the test file that I'm using which mimics our production code. Main exception is that in our production code we have a class that handles the database stuff. Either way, SIGABRT is thrown when the database is closed out. I've searched for answers and have found similar issues. The main conclusion to the issues was that the column family handlers were not being released from the database before closing. Also, there seems to have been a bug in previous releases of rocksdb concerning this. Is that bug still there? Am I just doing something incorrectly? Although not in this code, I have also tested with drop/destroy of the default column family too.

Rockdb version.h

```
#define ROCKSDB_MAJOR 6
#define ROCKSDB_MINOR 2
#define ROCKSDB_PATCH 0
```

Below is the test file:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <rocksdb/db.h>
#include <rocksdb/filter_policy.h>
#include <rocksdb/table.h>

namespace testing {

namespace {
    static const std::string db_directory                   = std::string("/tmp/database");
    static const std::string kFeaturesColumnFamilyName      = "keypoints_and_descriptors";
    static const std::string kMatchesColumnFamilyName       = "image_pair_matches";
    static const std::string kIntrinsicsColumnFamilyName    = "camera_intrinsics_prior";

}  // namespace

TEST(RocksdbColumnFamilyError, RocksBasicPointers) {
    std::unique_ptr<rocksdb::Options> options_;
    std::unique_ptr<rocksdb::DB> database_;
    std::unique_ptr<rocksdb::ColumnFamilyHandle> intrinsics_prior_handle_;
    std::unique_ptr<rocksdb::ColumnFamilyHandle> features_handle_;
    std::unique_ptr<rocksdb::ColumnFamilyHandle> matches_handle_;

    options_.reset(new rocksdb::Options);
    options_->max_background_jobs = 4;
    options_->db_write_buffer_size = 1 << 30;
    options_->bytes_per_sync = 1 << 20;
    options_->compaction_pri = rocksdb::kMinOverlappingRatio;
    options_->create_if_missing = true;
    options_->level_compaction_dynamic_level_bytes = true;
    options_->statistics = rocksdb::CreateDBStatistics();

    rocksdb::BlockBasedTableOptions table_options;
    table_options.block_cache = rocksdb::NewLRUCache(512 << 20);
    table_options.block_size = 16 * 1024;
    table_options.cache_index_and_filter_blocks = true;
    table_options.pin_l0_filter_and_index_blocks_in_cache = true;
    table_options.filter_policy.reset(rocksdb::NewBloomFilterPolicy(10, false));
    options_->table_factory.reset(rocksdb::NewBlockBasedTableFactory(table_options));

    std::vector<rocksdb::ColumnFamilyDescriptor> column_descriptors;
    column_descriptors.emplace_back(rocksdb::kDefaultColumnFamilyName, *options_);

    // Open the DB, creating it if necessary.
    rocksdb::DB* temp_db = nullptr;
    std::vector<rocksdb::ColumnFamilyHandle*> temp_col_family_handles;
    rocksdb::Status status = rocksdb::DB::Open(*options_,
                                               db_directory,
                                               column_descriptors,
                                               &temp_col_family_handles,
                                               &temp_db);

    // Take ownership of the database object.
    database_.reset(temp_db);

    // Create intrinsics_prior_handle_
    rocksdb::ColumnFamilyHandle * intrinsics_prior_;
    database_->CreateColumnFamily(*options_, kIntrinsicsColumnFamilyName, &intrinsics_prior_);
    intrinsics_prior_handle_.reset(intrinsics_prior_);

    // Create features_handle_
    rocksdb::ColumnFamilyHandle * features_;
    database_->CreateColumnFamily(*options_, kFeaturesColumnFamilyName, &features_);
    features_handle_.reset(features_);

    // Create matches_handle_
    rocksdb::ColumnFamilyHandle * matches_;
    database_->CreateColumnFamily(*options_, kMatchesColumnFamilyName, &matches_);
    matches_handle_.reset(matches_);

    /*
     * .... proform database operation get stuff, put stuff so on ....
     */

    // Drop handles
    database_->DropColumnFamily(intrinsics_prior_handle_.get());
    database_->DropColumnFamily(features_handle_.get());
    database_->DropColumnFamily(matches_handle_.get());

    // Destroy handles
    database_->DestroyColumnFamilyHandle(intrinsics_prior_handle_.get());
    database_->DestroyColumnFamilyHandle(features_handle_.get());
    database_->DestroyColumnFamilyHandle(matches_handle_.get());

    // Close db
    database_->Close();         // Causes SIGABRT
//    delete database_.get();     // Causes SIGABRT
//    rocksdb::DestroyDB(db_directory, rocksdb::Options());   // Causes SIGABRT  // Options doesn't have any affect
    rocksdb::DestroyDB(db_directory, *options_);            // Causes SIGABRT  // Options doesn't have any affect
}

}  // namespace testing
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dropping and Destroying ColumnFamilies that you have created, I think, you also need to Destroy the default column family.

```
database_->DestroyColumnFamilyHandle(default_family_handle_);
```

The default family should not be dropped.